# Installing WAMP Server on windows 7 64 bit OS

Tags: mysql

My Wamp Server is installed coorectly but, I can't access to PHPMyAdmin. 
Giving the error  ....

```
**ERROR**

 **MySQL said: Documentation**
 *1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.**
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the phpMyadmin first. Try this.
http://www.slideshare.net/triniwiz/wamp-20949805

Give attention to the slide 19. It will resolve your issue.

All you have to do is, 
Edit your phpmyadmin config.inc.php file :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '**your-root-username**';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '**root-password**';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

-Regards

Answer (score 0):

Change the following database config values in your config.default.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_Password';
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps!